# Why isn't the highest element not returning?

Tags: c, pointers, reference, dereference

I just learned about pointers and having trouble with this program. My int function is returning the first element of the array and not returning the highest element. I think I'm calling the wrong declaration to get the right element in the main, but I'm not sure that is true. Also what would NULL do if the size was equal to 0? This is my program so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *maxval(int *, int );

int main()
{
const int size=20;
int array[size]={21,1,33,15,11,5,2,29,
33,56,4,44,9,12,19,23,22,35,7,13};
int *arrPtr;
arrPtr=array;

cout<<"The numbers in set are: ";
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    cout<<*(array+i)<<" ";
}
maxval(array, size);
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Maximum element is: "<< *arrPtr<<endl;
return 0;
}

int *maxval(int *arr, int size)
{
int *maximum=arr;
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    if(arr[i] > *maximum || size != 0)
    {
        maximum=&arr[i];
        return maximum;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you expect it to be "returning" anything when you call your `maxval(array, size)` and completely *ignore* its return value??? You set your `arrPtr` to point to the first element of `array` and you never change it afterwards. No wonder your code always prints the first element.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong, not about pointers. You return NULL in the first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(arr[i] > *maximum || size != 0)
{
    maximum=&arr[i];
    return maximum;
}
else
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Here you are returning NULL as soon as a value is not greater than your current maximun. Which will happen in the first iteration.

You should remove both returns in the loop, and add:

```
return maximun
```

after the loop.

You should also, remove the condition

```
size != 0
```

Since it will always be true: In case size was 0 or less, the loop would never execute because of its end condition.

Comment: Thank you very much user2215331. It returns 56 as the highest. I have another question. How would I dereference the passbacked address and highest element? Or have I dereference them both?